# If there are two values, catch the 2, if isn't, catch the first with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm breaking my head to find a solution for this.

I need catch some specific values in a string. This string had this format before a treatment:

```
5593 DSR Sobreaviso   [ 032]   0,00 54,38
01 SRM Sim            [  01]        10,00
```

After the treatment, the string will be like this:

```
5593 DSR Sobreaviso [ 032] 0,00 54,38 01 SRM Sim [  01] 10,00
```

So.. i need catch the most right  values, which is the total, and i'm having a hard time to figure it out how to extract the second value if the first value exist, and extract the first value if the second value doesn't exist.

I'm trying like this:

```
/.*?\s(?:5593)\s.*?\s([\d.,]+)]\s([\d.,]+)/
```

I need explicity pass the most right value because this pieces are inside a huge text (more than 50k words).

Checkout this example: http://regexr.com/3cj6e

When i pass 5593, the regex will catch the 0,00, but i need the 54,38.. when i pass 01, the regex will catch the right value.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a regex, at least on its own, is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: `i'm having a hard time to figure it out how to extract the second value if the first value exist, and extract the first value if the second value doesn't exist."` - this is incredibly ambiguous

Comment: How is it? It's a simple request.. if the first value exist, ignore it and catch the second, if there isn't a second value, just catch the first one..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"treatment"*, and why don't you just add a pipe or something between the values and split

Comment: i'm replacing more than one space and line breaks for just one space. I didn't get your suggestion, can you explain me more?

Comment: Give us an example of the first value and the second value. First value is `5593` and second value is `DSR`? Or is the first value the entire first line?

Comment: The first value is 0,00 in the first line in the example, the second value is 54,38 in the first line in the example. The first value is 10,00 in the second line. I need catch this values by the most left number, so 5593 in the first line and 01 in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have your answer by now, but if not, does this help?

```
/\b(?:5593)\s+[\w ]+\s+\[[ \d]+\]\s+(?:[\d]+[.,][\d]+\s+)?([\d]+[.,][\d]+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
/[\d.,]+$/
```

http://regexr.com/3cj6k

It just looks for the last number on the line.

Edit:

From your comments I understand the question a little better.

How about something like this then:

```
/([\d.,]+)\s([\d.,]+)\s[a-z]/gi
```

Here it is inaction on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zzvur713/3/

Comment: I'm treatment the text, so there isn't lines Dylan.

Comment: I'm changing every more than one space and line breaks for one space.